# How to convert string to Object type in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

I have variable `$id="5fb3a0c67b5c000087002e60";` this is of type string in laravel & i want to convert this `$id` to type `ObjectId("5fb3a0c67b5c000087002e60")`.
when i fire query `$result = $collection->find(['_id'=>$id]);` # so here $id is of type string and value inside '_id' which is from mongodb database is of type ObjectId, So to get result from this query `$result = $collection->find(['_id'=>$id]);` I need to convert $id which is of **string** to **ObjectId**

Comment: Welcome to SO  ... does `ObjectId` have a constructor that takes a string?

Comment: Is this MongoDB related?

Comment: please specify why do you need that.

Comment: yes its mongodb related, when i fire query $result = $collection->find(['_id'=>$id]); # so here $id is of type string and value inside _id which is from mongodb database is of type ObjectId, So to get result from this query $result = $collection->find(['_id'=>$id]); I need to convert $id which is of string to ObjectId

Comment: I'd suggest you include all of this info in your question by clicking the `edit` link under it and also add the `mongodb` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MongoDB BSON library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-objectid.php).

Simply use the objectId object to create a new instance:

```
use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId;

$_id = new ObjectId($string_id);
```